# Urllib2 request for data from an HTTPS RSS feed returns garbage characters

Tags: python, rss, urllib2

I am trying to read the RSS feed of a website using HTTPS protocol with Phyton 2.7 and its urllib2 library. I can't use feedparser. This code snippet is taken from the [requests library github](https://gist.github.com/kennethreitz/973705#file-0_urllib2-py) (Which I tried to use but I kept getting errors like this: `requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'kat.cr' doesn't match either of '*.kickass.so', 'kickass.so'`, googling around revealed that I was not the only one who encountered this exact error for kickass).

```
import urllib2

gh_url = 'https://kat.cr/movies/?rss=1'

req = urllib2.Request(gh_url)

password_manager = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_manager.add_password(None, gh_url, 'user', 'pass')

auth_manager = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_manager)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_manager)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

handler = urllib2.urlopen(req)

print handler.read()
```

My problem is that the output of `handler.read()` is just a bunch of garbage characters. The code works for other HTTPS sites (I tried 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page' for example) or other RSS feeds (I tried 'http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture').

Why would it not work with this exact RSS feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didn't solve the problem with urllib2 but I figured out that you can use requests without specifying authorization like this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com', verify = False)
print r.read
```

and that gets rid of the error so you can read the data without a problem.